# How to fix overflow issue (just overflow-y visible)?

Tags: html, css

So I have a tabslider on my webpage and an image similar as stage above.
Now I want to popup some text when I hover over an `<li>`.
Because my list is actually I need to set overflow-x to hidden. The problem now is that my `<span class="info">` will be also hidden. If I set `overflow-x: hidden;` and `overflow-y: visible;` my `<ul>` can be scrolled to top. But my `<span class="info">` is still hidden.

```css
.list-wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

ul {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: visible;
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element-wrapper">
    <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">first</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Seconde</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Third</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

How it looks:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

Used Chrome 61.0.31

**UPDATE 2:
I need to set my `<ul>` to overflow-x: hidden!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using a tooltip. This overlaps this image.
I used [qTip2](http://qtip2.com/) as jQuery-Plugin. So I could set position and styles for my tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the wrapper overflow visible and ul as well then set the position of the ul and li position initial and triger the event only on hover like this:

```
.list-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    height: 40px;
    position: initial;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 40px;
    position: initial;
}
li:hover .info {
    display: block;
}

.info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

The only way you can do that is by using javascript and toggling some boxes outside of your ul on hover over ul > li. Something like this:

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
    .element-wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .element-wrapper img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .list-wrapper {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: visible;
    }

    .hover_wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .hover_wrapper .info {
        width: 19%;
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

    ul {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: visible;
        height: 40px;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 40px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .info {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 60px;
        left: 0;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.text').hover(function () {
                $('.info[data-id="' + $(this).data('hover') + '"]').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }, function () {
                $('.info[data-id="' + $(this).data('hover') + '"]').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element-wrapper">
        <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150">
        <div class="hover_wrapper">
            <span class="info" data-id="1">Information that should popup above the image</span>
            <span class="info" data-id="2">Information that should popup above the image</span>
            <span class="info" data-id="3">Information that should popup above the image</span>
            <span class="info" data-id="4">Information that should popup above the image</span>
            <span class="info" data-id="5">Information that should popup above the image</span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="link"><span class="text" data-hover="1">first</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="link"><span class="text" data-hover="2">Seconde</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="link"><span class="text" data-hover="3">Third</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="link"><span class="text" data-hover="4">Other</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="link"><span class="text" data-hover="5">Other Other</span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is that I need to set my <ul> to overflow-x: overflow. Because it is a tab-slider and should not overflow. With this solution my info-text is shown but my list is not overflow anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Give this css to img tag for responsive img.

```
img{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

```css
.element-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

ul { 
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element-wrapper">
    <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">first</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Seconde</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Third</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that doesn't show my <span class="info"> neither. @ankita patel

Comment: can you share any screenshot...?

Comment: Sure :) I updated my Post. Thats also how it looks like, when I edit your code. @ankita patel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is that I need to set my <ul> to overflow-x: overflow. Because it is a tab-slider and should not overflow. With this solution my info-text is shown but my list is not overflow anymore.

Answer (score 0):

check now it is display on hover

```css
.element-wrapper {
position: relative;
}

ul {
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
}

li .info{
  display:none;
}

li:hover .info
{
display:block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
img{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element-wrapper">
    <!--<div class="image"></div>-->
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/750x150">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">first</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Seconde</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Third</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="link"><span class="text">Other Other</span><span class="info">Information that should popup above the image</span></a></li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my problem is that I need to set my <ul> to overflow-x: overflow. Because it is a tab-slider and should not overflow. With this solution my info-text is shown but my list is not overflow anymore.